# Conditional string manipulation of all values in a column, Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, string

Given a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',], 
                   'COL2': ['gp.se', 'https://www.expressen.se/', 'http://friatider.se', 'http://www.klimatupplysningen.se']})
DF
```

I would like to check every value of COL2 and apply some old-school string editing along the lines of:

```
if string.starstwith('https://www'):
string.split('www.')[1][:-1])
elif string.startswith('http://') and string.endswith('/'):
string.split('www.')[1][:-1]
```

I then want to reassign the new edited string at the same cell in the dataframe. The result should be like this:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',], 
                       'COL2': ['gp.se', 'expressen.se', 'friatider.se', 'klimatupplysningen.se']})
    DF
```

Is there a way to use `df.loc` to elegantly replace strings, **reusing parts of the original string**, and applying the kind of if/else, startswith/endswith, string-slicing methods I am familiar with?

I am aware of the replace function, but would much prefer to do it this conditional way (my real df is much bigger and has much more values, and I would like to avoid having to replace them one by one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and then [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) with `.` and `/` (not letters  like `http://www`):

```
L = ['https://www','https://','http://www','http://']
DF['COL2'] = DF['COL2'].replace(L, '', regex=True).str.strip('[./]')
print (DF)
  COL1                   COL2
0    A                  gp.se
1    B           expressen.se
2    C           friatider.se
3    D  klimatupplysningen.se
```

Answer (score 1):

A different way would be using regex

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',], 
                   'COL2': ['gp.se', 'https://www.expressen.se/', 'http://friatider.se', 'http://www.klimatupplysningen.se']})


pattern = r'https{0,1}://w{0,3}\.{,1}'
print(df['COL2'].str.replace(pattern, '').str.strip('/'))
```

Comment: That's another good one, thanks! Is the first .str. needed? It's not in the first answer and that worked fine.

Comment: Good question! :) I use .str for parallelism